# Is there anyway to create a new OnsenUI project in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, onsen-ui

I wanted to use OnsenUI with Visual Studio 2013 but noticed that OnsenUI just seems to be a download of the project files.

Is there anyway to open the project in VS2013 or is it a case of creating my own project file in VS and including the project files manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Onsen UI for developing Web apps, you could just download from onsen.io and drag & drop to your solution.

For Cordova app development, "Monaca for Visual Studio" is the add-on extension that enables Onsen UI development using Monaca cloud. It provides a couple of Onsen UI project templates.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ed1f1bd-494e-45da-99ac-6e05b2648eef

Another option is to use Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova, and drag & drop Onsen UI contents.

https://www.visualstudio.com/explore/cordova-vs